# Access connectionfactory inside messageListener onMessage

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am creating a rabbitmq messageListener and would like to be able to access the connectionfactory configuration while in the onMessage method, is that possible?  It would be useful for logging and other details.  Being able to log the vhost from which the message was delivered would be helpful and it is not available in the message itself.  Here is my consumer and config

```
public class Consumer implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
    //how can I get the connection factory configuration when a message is     sent?
    }
```

here is the config

```
{
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class RabbitConfig {

    private static final String SIMPLE_MESSAGE_QUEUE = "qDLX2.dlq";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new     CachingConnectionFactory("server");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("admin");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("ad,om");
        connectionFactory.setPort(5672);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("vhost1");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }



    @Autowired
    private Consumer consumer;


    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
         SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();        
        listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        listenerContainer.setQueueNames(SIMPLE_MESSAGE_QUEUE);
        listenerContainer.setMessageListener(consumer);
        listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);      
        return listenerContainer;
    }


}
```

Thanks
Gregg

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way of doing that.

You could inject the connection factory into the `consumer` field in your `listenerContainer` bean definition...

```
listenerContainer.setMessageListener(this.consumer);
this.consumer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
```

You could probably `@Autowire` it too.

You can then use `getRabbitConnectionFactory().getVirtualHost()` to access the vhost.